# ClassCastException while Drag and Drop in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

I want to make drag and drop in `JTree`. I follow this tutorial:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DnDdraganddropJTreecode.htm

Unfortunately I have in `JTree` nodes with my own class and when I want to drag then I got this Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.
```

How to solve it? I need use `MyClass` instead of `DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

Comment: At which line do you have the exception? Please share the relevant part of your code, or even better try to post a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/mcve) demonstrating your problem (you might solve your problem in the process of making an MCVE).

Comment: On the other hand, the Exception is pretty self-explanatory: you are trying to cast a `MyClass` object as `DefaultMutableTreeNode`. If your `TreeModel` contains only `MyClass` node type then replace the down-casts to `MyClass` accordingly. For example: `MyClass  parent = (MyClass) parentpath.getLastPathComponent();`

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting [the example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DnDdraganddropJTreecode.htm) you are following and given you say you get the exception when you want to *drag* a node, I think this is the line (not the only line that has to be fixed though):

```
class TreeDragSource implements DragSourceListener, DragGestureListener {
    ...
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
        TreePath path = sourceTree.getSelectionPath();
        if ((path == null) || (path.getPathCount() <= 1)) {
          // We can't move the root node or an empty selection
          return;
        }
        oldNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent(); // ClassCastException Here!
        transferable = new TransferableTreeNode(path);
        source.startDrag(dge, DragSource.DefaultMoveNoDrop, transferable, this);
    }
    ...
}
```

So, if your [TreeModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) contains only `MyClass` type of node (I'm asssuming your class implements at least [TreeNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) interface, better if [MutableTreeNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/MutableTreeNode.html)) then you would have to down-cast the last path component to your class, accordingly:

```
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
        ...
        oldNode = (MyClass) path.getLastPathComponent();
        ...
    }
```

As I've said, you would have to replace all the down-casts from `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to `MyClass`. Of course this might cause other kind of exceptions but go one step at the time.